# What laws, if any, were violated and what are the theoretical penalties for breaking them associated with Trumps failure to disclose the 19.8 m loan?

Tags: united-states, president, loan

Trump having a foreign loan for 19.8m that wasn't disclosed is sort of big news now.  However, the news doesn't say much about the legal implications, many imply he violated a requirement to disclose but none give specifics of the legal implication.  I know Fobes at least had an article saying trump may not be technically guilty of violating a law, except the rest of the article is paywalled so I don't know why they thought that.

So basically what laws are relevant to the non-disclosed loan, how likely is it that trump is actually guilty of violating them, and if he were guilty what penalties does the law outline for breaking it?